# how to bind "spring.datasource.tomcat" properties to javax.sql.DataSource class in spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, tomcat-jdbc

I have some code that works properly on spring boot prior to version 2 and I find it hard to convert it to work with spring boot 2.

Can somebody assist?

yml file:

```
spring:
   datasource:
      type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
      tomcat:
         initial-size: 10
         max-active: 20
         max-idle: 10
         max-wait: 10000
```

Old code:

```
       DataSource dataSource = builder.build();

        Map<String, Object> properties = null;

            try {
                RelaxedPropertyResolver relaxedProperty = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment);
                properties = relaxedProperty
                    .getSubProperties("spring.datasource.tomcat.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  // No need to log an error
            }
            MutablePropertyValues mutableProperties = new MutablePropertyValues(properties);            
            if(properties == null || properties.isEmpty()) {

                return dataSource;
            }
            new RelaxedDataBinder(dataSource).bind(mutableProperties);

            return dataSource;
```

New Code with version 2:

```
   DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder =  
   DataSourceBuilder.create(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    javax.sql.DataSource dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.build();

        Map<String, Object> properties = null;

            try {

                properties = Binder.get(environment)
                        .bind("spring.datasource.tomcat", Bindable.mapOf(String.class, Object.class)).orElseGet(Collections::emptyMap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                  // No need to log an error
            }
            if(properties == null || properties.isEmpty()) {
                return dataSource;
            }
            return Binder.get(environment)
                     .bind("spring.datasource.tomcat", DataSource.class).get();
```

I am getting below error while binding data to DataSource.class. When I replace datasource to poolProperties class, it will able to bind but I am not able to bind this datasource.
                Binder.get(environment)
                         .bind("spring.datasource.tomcat", PoolProperties.class).get();:

Error:

```
   java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value bound
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindResult.get(BindResult.java:56)
```

Comment: How this works for you javax.sql.DataSource dataSource = new 
   DataSourceBuilder(this.getClass().getClassLoader()).build();
Intellij says 'DataSourceBuilder(java.lang.ClassLoader)' has private access in 'org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder'

Comment: Updated the code. Please check. Thanks

Comment: You have to move the "type" and "tomcat" block one more time with spaces.

Comment: Oops, it was typo, I'll edit here. In my application, there is space before type and tomcat. Are you able to find after moving these? I am able to read these values from yaml using binder but not able to map it to data source class